# How to extract reCAPTCHA from a website and solve it externally?

Tags: javascript, python, recaptcha, captcha, grecaptcha

I would like to know if there's any possibililty to extract reCATPCHA from any website and solve it externally, as form example, 2captcha.com does. Since it just asks you for the data-sitekey and page url (https://2captcha.com/2captcha-api#solving_recaptchav2_new), to solve it.

So I'm curious about it. Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking how to bypass site security? That doesn't sound good.

Comment: Hi, Absolutely no! I'm just curious how is that possible, I just want to see how to solve recaptcha externally!